# How to determine that two HTML events have the same origin (and then determine "event was processed already")

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

How to determine that two HTML events have the same origin? What I need is to process click event only once (without stopPropogation because stopPropogation of clicks is "not friednly to dropdowns, modals, etc")

Comparision by originalEvent (using jQuery) `if (event.originalEvent != processedEvent.originalEvent)` works well, but I want to do the same in vanilla js.

Do we have convinient pure js method to do the same?

```js
var processedEvent = null;

$("#myButton").click(
   function(event){
       console.log("this should be processed once")
       processedEvent = event;
       
   }
)

$("#myPanel").click(
   function(event){
       if (event.originalEvent == processedEvent.originalEvent)
          console.log("nice. we are going to ingore event")
       else
          console.log("error. event processed second time")
       processedEvent=null;
   }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myPanel">
<button id="myButton">Click Me jQuery</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: As far as I can tell `originalEvent` is a jQuery thing, so you should be fine to use it.

Comment: @AndreNuechter  thank you!... chmmm... relly on jQuery is also not what I want... I'm going to rewrite it without jQuery ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PreventDefault is a pretty standard way to do this. You call `event.preventDefault()` in your innermost handler, then your outer one should check `if (!event.isDefaultPrevented()) {` for  jquery, or `if (!event.defaultPrevented) {` for vanilla js.

You can add custom properties to the event object as flags, like `event._customWasHandled = true`, then check for those properties in later handlers.

Comment: Psst: `jQueryEvent.isDefaultPrevented()` only maps to [`Event.defaultPrevented`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/defaultPrevented), i.e jQuery is not required here.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated it with a more vanilla explanation. I've always used jquery for more browser compatibility, so I'm more used to its syntax. FYI, `event.defaultPrevented` is supported down to IE9, so no compatibility issues here.

Answer (score 0):

I was blind. In vanilla javascript  opposite to jQuery events are the same...

```js
var processedEvent = null;

document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
       if (!event.target.matches('#myButton2')) return;
         console.log("this should be processed once")
      processedEvent = event;
}, false);

document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
   if (event == processedEvent)
          console.log("nice. we are going to ingore event")
      else
          console.log("error. event processed second time")
      processedEvent=null;
}, false);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myPanel2">
<button id="myButton2">Click Me Vanilla</button>
</div>
```